# <h:dataTable value is not null, but the page is empty

Tags: jsf

I have two dataTables, one nest anther. The code as below :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{allUserBean.userList}" var="pmUsers">
  <h:column headerClass="tableHeader column8Header">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:commandLink actionListener="#{allUser.sortByEmpNo}" immediate="true">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="colSortText,colSortImg">
          <h:outputText value="Emp No." />
          <h:panelGrid rendered="#{allUserBean.sortType == 0}">
            <h:graphicImage url="/images/sortup.gif" rendered="#{allUserBean.up}" />
            <h:graphicImage url="/images/sortdown.gif" rendered="#{!allUserBean.up}" />
          </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{pmUsers.employeeNo}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:dataTable  var="iterm" value="#{pmUsers.userMultyResumeList}"">                       
    <h:outputText value="#{iterm}" />
  </h:dataTable> `
```

The  show successful, but the other dataTable of userMultyResumeList can't be showed. 
I used the testing code , it is false. so the value is not null, i don't know why

The userList code as :

```
private List<User> userList;
userList = userService.getUsersByPMGroupNotIncluded("", groupIds);
```

Comment: try printing size of the list pmUsers.userMultyResumeList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:dataTable  var="iterm" value="#{pmUsers.userMultyResumeList}"">
```

Please repalce this line with this

```
<h:dataTable  var="iterm" value="#{pmUsers.userMultyResumeList}">
```

Comment: I have resolved it. Because there is an issue of these code:    <h:dataTable  var="iterm" value="#{pmUsers.userMultyResumeList}"">                       
    <h:outputText value="#{iterm}" />                                                                                                                                      
  </h:dataTable>                                                       It need to add a <h:column> to bracket the output text. Thanks all the same